# Java compiles from command line but not from Maven

Tags: maven, java-ee-6

I have my system set up to compile jee6 code from the command line (no IDE). I recently tried to compile some code that uses javax.enterprise.context.RequestedScope. The code compiled fine from the command prompt but when I tried to build the application using Maven I keep getting javax.enterprise.context package not found error.

What gives? I thought Maven was using the same javac I'm using. Why can javac find the package but Maven can't? Do I need to add dependencies for java packages?

Or...is there a way to tell Maven to use the current class files when building or does Maven have to compile when it builds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the Java EE 6 jar to your Maven dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    . . .
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This will add the Java EE classes to your compile-time classpath.

Answer (score 0):

To compile your code with Maven, you need to tell it where to find required components.

Looks like you need to add this to your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note the `<scope>` element. It tells Maven not to bundle this dependency with your artifact, because at run time it will be *provided* by the application container.

On the reason why it compiles from the command line.
You probably have the required jar file on the command line `-cp` option or in your global `CLASSPATH` variable.

Maven, by design, does not pay attention to the global `CLASSPATH`.